# How to get EditText ellipsized?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I tried to get EditText ellipsied when the EditText lose focus, but it does not work.
The following is my xml:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="11111sdsssssskdkdjdjdjddhhdhdhhdh"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

can somebody can help me?

Comment: It will only get ellipsized after it exceeds the width you set for the view.

Comment: android:ellipsize is broken for edit text, it will not ellipsize even when text is much longer than the view width.

Answer (score 5):

Using XML:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
android:editable="false"
```

Programmatically:

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
editText.setSingleLine();
editText.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
editText.setKeyListener(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

```
<EditText
 android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
 android: layout_height = "40dip"
 android: textSize = "14dip"
 android: singleLine = "true" />
```

When text is too long will automatically display an ellipsis, the API which also stresses the android: the singleLine = "true", it will have this effect.  Without ellipsize = "end".

Comment: This does not ellipsize the text, it merely truncates it.

Comment: Does that really work ? I have tried all possible combinations on 4.2.2 . Nothing seems to work